# Cannot get data to show (Highstock)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The following code displays a blank chart (axes and title are displayed OK but no data), and I cannot understand why. It doesn't seem to be a data format problem, as I followed the documentation. Logging the options to Firebug shows that "series" is null.

```
var chart1;
var data;

options = {
    chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
        animation: Highcharts.svg,              
    },           
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: { //--- Primary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        }
    },              
    series: [{
        name: 'name',
        step: true,
        data: data
    }]
};

console.log(options); //series is null here !

function readData() {
    //using foo data here, actually getting it via AJAX, and that works OK
    data = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]];
    alert("data created");

    //this checks that the data loaded OK
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += 'Key: ' + data[i][0] + '; Value: ' + data[i][1] + "<br />";
    }
    chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
}
```

Here's what I include :

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="XHR.js"></script><!-- unrelated (for ajax) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Does your browser console display any error ?

Comment: No, neither the normal dev console in Firefox nor Firebug.

Comment: How can I log the plot options like this guy did : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590162/highcharts-loading-data-and-not-plotting ?

Comment: use console.log(options) and view it in the firebug console

Comment: Thanks ! Well, series is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course data is null because you aren't asigning it to options, add this line:

```
options.series[0].data = data;
```

AFTER data from AJAX comes. For example before you are creating chart (`chart1 = ...`).

Comment: Thank you, actually I went for `data: []` and call `chart1.series[0].setData(data);` at the right moment. Works better.

Comment: Yes, that's also possible.